# asp.NET - dataset.xsd failed to generate code after being uploaded to domain

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, xsd, dataset

I've recently been working on a small website for a friend, after creating the website, where all works as intended, it stops working when being uploaded to the server.

So far I know that the Dataset.xsd is unable to generate the needed code based on the .xsd file, and that it has something to do with the fact, that the file locations are being changed. All of this I've learned by browsing here.

I use MySQL, and my target server uses phpMyAdmin, so I can't use remote access.
Is there a workaround for this, or what am I doing wrong?

The error occurs at Line 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

With this exception

```
Failed to generate code. Exception of type 'System.Data.Design.InternalException' was thrown.
```